# Does activity has cache?

Tags: android-activity

I found a problem,when I goto Activity A at first time, it will call 3 times OnLayout.  And then I press back to destroy the activity,and then goto the activity again, it will call only 1 times OnLayout.Is it normal? Does activity has cache?

Comment: Your activity has the `savedInstanceState`. Wich means if you go from Activity `A` to `B`, it will save and restore the state from `A` when pressing the back-button. To clear this activity you can use `Classname.this.finish();` to clear activity `A` and start a new one on `B`.

Comment: oh,no. I meant go from A to B,B call three times onLayout,and then I press back to return to A. And then click button to change activity A to B, B call ONLY one time onLayout

Comment: Oh, in that case, I don't know if this is a cache issue.

Comment: Thank you all the same. I am so surprised when I found this problem, I have never heard somethins about activity cache